RequestAuthentication fails when Istio sidecar config is enabled
I'm running a local Kubernetes cluster with Istio installed onto it. I have one authorization server running in a deployment in the namespace "authserver", and one resource server running in a deployment in the namespace "resourceserver". Each of these deployments have a ClusterIP service in front of them to expose them internally to the cluster.
I also have an Istio RequestAuthentication and AuthorizationPolicy resource in front of the resourceserver service.
The RequestAuthentication looks like this:
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: resource-service-auth
  namespace: resourceserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-resource
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: "http://authorization-service.authserver"
      audiences:
        - "client"
      jwksUri: "http://authorization-service.authserver/oauth2/jwks"

And the AuthorizationPolicy looks like this:
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: resource-service-authz
  namespace: resourceserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-resource
  action: DENY
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]

This successfully blocks requests with invalid JWTs, and allows requests with valid JWTs.
HOWEVER, once I add this Istio Sidecar object to the resource server, I start getting the error "Jwks doesn't have key to match kid or alg from Jwt" when making requests with valid JWTs to my resource server:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: resourceservice-sidecar
  namespace: resourceserver
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: resourceservice
  egress:
    - hosts:
        - "authservice/*"
  outboundTrafficPolicy:
    mode: REGISTRY_ONLY

I get this error: "Jwks doesn't have key to match kid or alg from Jwt".
If I set PILOT_JWT_ENABLE_REMOTE_JWKS to "envoy" so that Istiod no longer makes the calls to the JWKs URL, I instead get this error: "Jwks remote fetch is failed".
Does anyone know why this is? Is my sidecar config wrong somehow? Why does adding a sidecar to my resource server mess up my auth?

Hi, i am experiencing the same issue, did you manage to find a fix?
